# comparison: as clever students as we are

Tags: comparison

The following are all okay:

> a. They are as clever as we are.

> b. He is as clever as we are.

> c. He is as clever a student as we are.

What about the following?

> d. They are as clever students as we are.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, and grammatically, your 4th example of "They are as clever students as we are" is not wrong or incorrect.  That said, it is awkward and unnatural to phrase it this way.

In this example, "clever students" *could* be parsed as if it was a single adjective; in the way that you could say someone is "a tall person", we'd thus apply this parsing as "a clever student person".  But parsing it this way would be incorrect grammar, which is why it is unnatural to use this construction, even though this parsing is not forced, and there does exist a grammatical structure that does work here!

But adding an additional word will make your example much better:

> They are as clever **as** students as we are.

You could even go further, expanding out the meaning of the new additional as more explicitly:

> They are as clever **at being** students as we are.
> They are as clever **in their role** as students as we are.

But all of these tend to be less idiomatic, even if they aren't as likely to be misinterpreted as having bad grammar.  English speakers would find it unusual that you want to specify that both they and we are students.  Why is that important to say?  That's why your first example is better and would be much more common to hear by native speakers.

If you really want to emphasize that they are students, you could put that information elsewhere in the sentence:

> **Those students** are as clever as we are.

Of course, this only talks about them, but presumably "we" know who we are already.  It would be strange to have to say it again.